# Update cell in struct list and return the list

Tags: c

I'm looking for a way to update a cell in a struct list.
I have a struct list:

```
struct _list {
  int startNode,
      targetNode,
      substitute;
  unsigned char letter;
  struct _list *next;
}
```

And a function that enables me to update a cell.

```
struct _list *insertSubstitute(struct _list *list, int startNode,
    unsigned char letter, int substitute) {
  while (list != NULL) {
      if (list -> letter == letter && list -> startNode == startNode) {
        list -> substitute = substitute;
        return list;
      }
      list = list -> next;
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

My problem is that this function do not return the whole list. How could I proceed to do so?

Comment: `insertSubstitute` gets a pointer to a struct, so you are modifying the source. Why do you want to return it?

Comment: Changed your function prototype from 'struct _list*' list to 'struct _list**', you cannot modify a pointer and return it back but you can modify a pointer when you pass a pointer to the pointer, you will need to change internal references to list to '(*list)->, if you do this then you can get rid of the return and change the function return to void.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new var `whole_list`.

The following `code` could work:

```
struct _list *insertSubstitute(struct _list *list,
                               int startNode,
                               unsigned char letter,
                               int substitute) {

  struct _list* whole_list = list;

  while (list != NULL) {
      if (list -> letter == letter && list -> startNode == startNode) {
        list -> substitute = substitute;
        break;
      }
      list = list -> next;
  }
  return whole_list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need just to use a temporary pointer to your list to check the elements since you are using the list it self its causing you the problem

```
struct _list *insertSubstitute(struct _list *list, int startNode,
unsigned char letter, int substitute) {
 struct _list *temp=list;
 while (temp!= NULL) {
   if (temp-> letter == letter && temp-> startNode == startNode) {
    temp -> substitute = substitute;
    break;
  }
  temp= temp-> next;
  }
   return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    void insertSubstitute(struct _list** list
                         ,int startNode
                         ,unsigned char letter
                         ,int substitute) {
       if ( list == NULL ) {
    //Do nothing list is invalid
          return;
       }
       while (*list != NULL) {
          if ((*list) -> letter == letter && (*list) -> startNode == startNode) {
            (*list) -> substitute = substitute;
            return;
          }
          (*list) = (*list) -> next;
       }
    }
```

When you call this version of the function, you need to pass the address of your list.

Or another version of the original:

```
    struct _list*insertSubstitute(struct _list* list
                                 ,int startNode
                                 ,unsigned char letter
                                 ,int substitute) {
       if ( list == NULL ) {
    //Do nothing list is invalid
          return;
       }
       struct _list* rc = list;
       while (rc != NULL) {
          if (rc -> letter == letter && rc -> startNode == startNode) {
            rc -> substitute = substitute;
            return rc;
          }
          rc = rc -> next;
       }
       return NULL;
    }
```